# What study design is used in this research?

Tags: research, clinical-study, radiology

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1939865415001113

I've learned about many types of study design including experimental (randomised control trials etc.) and observational study types (cohort studies, cross sectional studies, case-control studies) etc. but a lot of the research articles I'm reading do not seem to fit into any of these design types and am not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Basically, the article linked above involves radiologist doctors rating x-ray images based on their quality (sharpness, amount of noise etc.). Some x-ray images have been obtained u
sing 30% less radiation and some have been obtained using 20% less radiation than a standard dose image. And they want to see if these lower radiation dose images are of acceptable quality.
The x-rays were taken on a phantom "dummy", not real patients. There was no random allocation, so can't be an RCT etc. yet it is experimental. I feel like I'm missing something and that the study designs I've been taught about don't fit studies like this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Link requires a login.

Comment: sorry, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1939865415001113        hopefully that should take you to the abstract, the full article doesn't really give much more information on the study design, they basically take x-rays themselves on a phantom at different radiation doses and get doctors to look and rate them to see if the lower dose ones are of sufficient quality. The xray images were randomised and image rating involved three questions and they were asked to give their answers by circling one number on a 1 to 5 scale. They then did stat tests to analyse the data. Thanks

Comment: Article title- Examining Practitioners' Assessments of Perceived Aesthetic and Diagnostic Quality of High kVp–Low mAs Pelvis, Chest, Skull, and Hand Phantom Radiographs

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: Is this for a course assignment?

Comment: Hi, yes it is for an assignment

Comment: I'd suggest then that you apply the concepts you've learned in the course. What types of study have you learned about, and which can you exclude and why? Make sure you use the actual definitions and not just your conception of what the types look like.